# How to resolve Disallowed Key Characters in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a question, I tried to export a pdf document using CodeIgniter, but I get an error :Disallowed Key Characters.
My html is :

```
<a href="<?=base_url()."dosar/generateTitlePage/$d[name_firm]'/'$d[number_certificate]'    /'$d[adresse_beneficiar]'/'$d[fk_user]'/'$d[fk_verificator]'/'$d[number]'/'$d[executor]'/'$d[date]" ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm marg-top-10">Title Page</a><br>
```

My php:

```
 public function generateTitlePage($company, $number_cadastral, $adresa_beneficiar, $administrator, $verificator, $number_certificate, $executor, $date)
{
    $search = array('%27', '%20', '%C3%A2', '%C3%AE', '%C4%83','%C5%A3', '%C4%82','%C3%8E', '%C3%82', '%C5%9E', '%C5%A2', '%C5%9F');
    $replace = array('', ' ', 'â', 'î' , 'ă', 'ţ', 'Ă', 'Î', 'Â', 'Ş', 'Ţ', 'ş');
    $company = str_replace($search, $replace, $company);
    $number_cadastral = str_replace($search, $replace, $number_cadastral);
    $adresa_beneficiar = str_replace($search, $replace, $adresa_beneficiar);
    $administrator = str_replace($search, $replace, $administrator);
    $verificator = str_replace($search, $replace, $verificator);
    $number_certificate = str_replace($search, $replace, $number_certificate);
    $executor = str_replace($search, $replace, $executor);
    $date = str_replace($search, $replace, $date);


    $html = '
        <html>
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        </head>
        <body>
        ......
        </body>
        </html>
         ';
      }
```

Help me please, Exist a solution?

Comment: Whats this `'`? a lot of single quotes in your `href` attribute for?

Comment: `applications/config/config.php` ?

Comment: $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

Comment: What is the output of the HTML not the PHP code but in browser link url?